# How can I know that 2 x-bee are paired before or not?

Tags: wireless, xbee

I got 2 x-bee from my school lab, and I want to use it. These 2 x-bee are paired before or not, how can I check it? What should I do to know whether it is paired or not?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You need to be more descriptive in your question about your situation (click the `edit` button). What model X-Bee devices do you have? What interface will you use with the devices? Also, have you contacted the lab admin for documentation or instructions on these devices?

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the exact part number of the XBee modules you are using, and then determine whether that part number corresponds to a "Series 1" module (e.g., IEEE 802.15.4) or a "Series 2" (a.k.a. ZigBee) module.
2. Visit Digi International's [XBEE/RF SOLUTIONS](http://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions) website and download the reference manuals (PDF files) for the specific XBee modules you are using.
3. Numerous "quick start guides" are available on the Internet pertaining to XBee "Series 1" and "Series 2" modules. For example, see [Exploring XBees and XCTU](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/exploring-xbees-and-xctu) on the [SparkFun Electronics](https://www.sparkfun.com/) website, or this step-by-step guide titled [Basic XBee ZB ZigBee (Series 2) Chat](http://examples.digi.com/get-started/basic-xbee-zb-zigbee-chat/) on Digi International's website.

Optional but strongly recommended: Purchase at least one (preferably two) XBee breakout boards (a.k.a., XBee explorer boards) with a built-in USB connector so that you can connect your XBee module to a USB port on your computer. Various companies sell these breakout boards (perform an Internet search using the keywords "xbee breakout usb" or "xbee explorer usb"). In addition, you'll want to download and install on your computer the [XCTU software](http://www.digi.com/products/xbee-rf-solutions/xctu-software/xctu) from Digi International's website. Note that in order to USE the XCTU software on a PC running Windows 7 (or later) you must log in as a user who has administrator privileges.

**:: CAUTION ::**

One final cautionary note. All XBee modules operate off a 3.3 VDC voltage supply, and therefore they operate using 3.3 Volt logic signals. **NEVER** connect a 5 Volt logic output signal to an XBee 3.3 Volt logic input; doing so will damage the XBee module. Companies like SparkFun Electronics, Adafruit Industries, etc. sell **bi-directional logic level converter** boards if you need to connect, say, a digital output signal from an Arduino Uno (5 Volt logic) to an XBee module (3.3 Volt logic), or vice versa.